Ubuntu 22.04 on Raspberry Pi 4B can't connect to teensy 4.1 via USB
I have been trying to connect my Teensy 4.1 to a RaspberryPi 4B running Ubuntu 22.04 via USB, but no USB device is identified.
Programming and serial communication works fine with THAT Teensy and THAT USB cable using an available Windows or Ubuntu PC.
I dont need to programm the Teensy with the Raspberry, I just want to use the serial port for communication.
I have checked:

All USB ports on Raspberry work fine with a keyboard
the Teensy is getting power (blinking light demo code running)
Teensy and cable work with other devices (Wiondows/Ubuntu PC)
No other devices are plugged into the raspberry (max USB current of raspberry: 1.2A | max current draw of Teensy: 0.1A), so power should not be a problem
installed/uninstalled the arduino IDE over apt and from appimage
installed raspi-config tool and set The serial login shell is disabled and The serial interfac is enabled (tried both options on/off)
checked that enable_uart=1 is set in boot/firmware/config.txt

I'm out of ideas and would be glad if anyone has some for debugging.
Thanks
When I run sudo dmesg -w to check the USB logs I (mostly) get the following output when plugging in the teensy (on each port):
[   644.208770] usb 1-1-port3: Cannot enable, Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[   645.060711] usb 1-1-port3: Cannot enable, Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[   645.061425] usb 1-1-port3: attempt power cycle
[   646.228786] usb 1-1-port3: Cannot enable, Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[   647.080742] usb 1-1-port3: Cannot enable, Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[   648.081438] usb 1-1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device

"Sometimes" the output is different, it detects a device but then after a while still can't enable it:
[  608.336004] usb 1-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  609.188025] usb 1-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  609.188749] usb 1-1-port4: attempt power cycle
[  610.376020] usb 1-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  610.455445] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[  610.455746] usb 1-1.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[  610.663784] usb 1-1.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[  610.871532] usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 12, error -71
[  610.872241] usb 1-1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
[  611.868079] usb 1-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  611.947504] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[  612.804093] usb 1-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  612.804879] usb 1-1-port4: attempt power cycle
[  613.972059] usb 1-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  614.055538] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[  614.055871] usb 1-1.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[  614.263814] usb 1-1.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[  614.471587] usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 16, error -71
[  614.472227] usb 1-1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
[  615.468106] usb 1-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  616.340156] usb 1-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  616.340866] usb 1-1-port4: attempt power cycle
[  617.508163] usb 1-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  617.587605] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[  617.587934] usb 1-1.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[  617.795902] usb 1-1.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[  618.003595] usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 20, error -71
[  618.004092] usb 1-1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
[  618.231669] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[  619.084219] usb 1-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  619.163649] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
[  620.016179] usb 1-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  620.016938] usb 1-1-port4: attempt power cycle
[  621.184327] usb 1-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  622.060362] usb 1-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  622.061128] usb 1-1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device

Output of lsusb: (doesn't matter if teensy is plugged in or not)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Output of sudo lsusb -v: (teensy plugged into port 3(Bus 001 Device 002))
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            5.15
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 5.15.0-1048-raspi dwc2_hsotg
  iProduct                2 DWC OTG Controller
  iSerial                 1 fe980000.usb
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             1
  wHubCharacteristic 0x0008
    Ganged power switching
    Per-port overcurrent protection
    TT think time 8 FS bits
  bPwrOn2PwrGood        1 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0000
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         3 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0003 3.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            5.15
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 5.15.0-1048-raspi xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:01:00.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x001f
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
        bMaxBurst               0
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              12
  bDescriptorType      42
  nNbrPorts             4
  wHubCharacteristic 0x0009
    Per-port power switching
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       50 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  bHubDecLat          0.0 micro seconds
  wHubDelay             0 nano seconds
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 2: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 3: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 4: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x000f
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x02
      Latency Tolerance Messages (LTM) Supported
    wSpeedsSupported   0x0008
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat           4 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat         231 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x2109 VIA Labs, Inc.
  idProduct          0x3431 Hub
  bcdDevice            4.21
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                1 USB2.0 Hub
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0001  1x 1 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             4
  wHubCharacteristic 0x00e0
    Ganged power switching
    Ganged overcurrent protection
    TT think time 32 FS bits
    Port indicators
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       50 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent    100 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
   Port 3: 0000.0101 power connect
   Port 4: 0000.0100 power
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x002a
  bNumDeviceCaps          3
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      HIRD Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat           4 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat         231 micro seconds
  Container ID Device Capability:
    bLength                20
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      4
    bReserved               0
    ContainerID             {30eef35c-07d5-2549-b001-802d79434c30}
cannot read device status, Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            5.15
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 5.15.0-1048-raspi xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:01:00.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             1
  wHubCharacteristic 0x0009
    Per-port power switching
    Per-port overcurrent protection
    TT think time 8 FS bits
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x02
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0503 highspeed power enable connect
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Output of ls /sys/class/tty:
~$ ls /sys/class/tty
console  ptycb  ptyp8  ptys5  ptyv2  ptyxf  tty19  tty6     ttyc4  ttyp1      ttyrd  ttyu9  ttyx6
ptmx     ptycc  ptyp9  ptys6  ptyv3  ptyy0  tty2   tty60    ttyc5  ttyp2      ttyre  ttyua  ttyx7
ptya0    ptycd  ptypa  ptys7  ptyv4  ptyy1  tty20  tty61    ttyc6  ttyp3      ttyrf  ttyub  ttyx8
ptya1    ptyce  ptypb  ptys8  ptyv5  ptyy2  tty21  tty62    ttyc7  ttyp4      ttys0  ttyuc  ttyx9
ptya2    ptycf  ptypc  ptys9  ptyv6  ptyy3  tty22  tty63    ttyc8  ttyp5      ttyS0  ttyud  ttyxa
ptya3    ptyd0  ptypd  ptysa  ptyv7  ptyy4  tty23  tty7     ttyc9  ttyp6      ttys1  ttyue  ttyxb
ptya4    ptyd1  ptype  ptysb  ptyv8  ptyy5  tty24  tty8     ttyca  ttyp7      ttys2  ttyuf  ttyxc
ptya5    ptyd2  ptypf  ptysc  ptyv9  ptyy6  tty25  tty9     ttycb  ttyp8      ttys3  ttyv0  ttyxd
ptya6    ptyd3  ptyq0  ptysd  ptyva  ptyy7  tty26  ttya0    ttycc  ttyp9      ttys4  ttyv1  ttyxe
ptya7    ptyd4  ptyq1  ptyse  ptyvb  ptyy8  tty27  ttya1    ttycd  ttypa      ttys5  ttyv2  ttyxf
ptya8    ptyd5  ptyq2  ptysf  ptyvc  ptyy9  tty28  ttya2    ttyce  ttypb      ttys6  ttyv3  ttyy0
ptya9    ptyd6  ptyq3  ptyt0  ptyvd  ptyya  tty29  ttya3    ttycf  ttypc      ttys7  ttyv4  ttyy1
ptyaa    ptyd7  ptyq4  ptyt1  ptyve  ptyyb  tty3   ttya4    ttyd0  ttypd      ttys8  ttyv5  ttyy2
ptyab    ptyd8  ptyq5  ptyt2  ptyvf  ptyyc  tty30  ttya5    ttyd1  ttype      ttys9  ttyv6  ttyy3
ptyac    ptyd9  ptyq6  ptyt3  ptyw0  ptyyd  tty31  ttya6    ttyd2  ttypf      ttysa  ttyv7  ttyy4
ptyad    ptyda  ptyq7  ptyt4  ptyw1  ptyye  tty32  ttya7    ttyd3  ttyprintk  ttysb  ttyv8  ttyy5
ptyae    ptydb  ptyq8  ptyt5  ptyw2  ptyyf  tty33  ttya8    ttyd4  ttyq0      ttysc  ttyv9  ttyy6
ptyaf    ptydc  ptyq9  ptyt6  ptyw3  ptyz0  tty34  ttya9    ttyd5  ttyq1      ttysd  ttyva  ttyy7
ptyb0    ptydd  ptyqa  ptyt7  ptyw4  ptyz1  tty35  ttyaa    ttyd6  ttyq2      ttyse  ttyvb  ttyy8
ptyb1    ptyde  ptyqb  ptyt8  ptyw5  ptyz2  tty36  ttyab    ttyd7  ttyq3      ttysf  ttyvc  ttyy9
ptyb2    ptydf  ptyqc  ptyt9  ptyw6  ptyz3  tty37  ttyac    ttyd8  ttyq4      ttyt0  ttyvd  ttyya
ptyb3    ptye0  ptyqd  ptyta  ptyw7  ptyz4  tty38  ttyad    ttyd9  ttyq5      ttyt1  ttyve  ttyyb
ptyb4    ptye1  ptyqe  ptytb  ptyw8  ptyz5  tty39  ttyae    ttyda  ttyq6      ttyt2  ttyvf  ttyyc
ptyb5    ptye2  ptyqf  ptytc  ptyw9  ptyz6  tty4   ttyaf    ttydb  ttyq7      ttyt3  ttyw0  ttyyd
ptyb6    ptye3  ptyr0  ptytd  ptywa  ptyz7  tty40  ttyAMA0  ttydc  ttyq8      ttyt4  ttyw1  ttyye
ptyb7    ptye4  ptyr1  ptyte  ptywb  ptyz8  tty41  ttyb0    ttydd  ttyq9      ttyt5  ttyw2  ttyyf
ptyb8    ptye5  ptyr2  ptytf  ptywc  ptyz9  tty42  ttyb1    ttyde  ttyqa      ttyt6  ttyw3  ttyz0
ptyb9    ptye6  ptyr3  ptyu0  ptywd  ptyza  tty43  ttyb2    ttydf  ttyqb      ttyt7  ttyw4  ttyz1
ptyba    ptye7  ptyr4  ptyu1  ptywe  ptyzb  tty44  ttyb3    ttye0  ttyqc      ttyt8  ttyw5  ttyz2
ptybb    ptye8  ptyr5  ptyu2  ptywf  ptyzc  tty45  ttyb4    ttye1  ttyqd      ttyt9  ttyw6  ttyz3
ptybc    ptye9  ptyr6  ptyu3  ptyx0  ptyzd  tty46  ttyb5    ttye2  ttyqe      ttyta  ttyw7  ttyz4
ptybd    ptyea  ptyr7  ptyu4  ptyx1  ptyze  tty47  ttyb6    ttye3  ttyqf      ttytb  ttyw8  ttyz5
ptybe    ptyeb  ptyr8  ptyu5  ptyx2  ptyzf  tty48  ttyb7    ttye4  ttyr0      ttytc  ttyw9  ttyz6
ptybf    ptyec  ptyr9  ptyu6  ptyx3  tty    tty49  ttyb8    ttye5  ttyr1      ttytd  ttywa  ttyz7
ptyc0    ptyed  ptyra  ptyu7  ptyx4  tty0   tty5   ttyb9    ttye6  ttyr2      ttyte  ttywb  ttyz8
ptyc1    ptyee  ptyrb  ptyu8  ptyx5  tty1   tty50  ttyba    ttye7  ttyr3      ttytf  ttywc  ttyz9
ptyc2    ptyef  ptyrc  ptyu9  ptyx6  tty10  tty51  ttybb    ttye8  ttyr4      ttyu0  ttywd  ttyza
ptyc3    ptyp0  ptyrd  ptyua  ptyx7  tty11  tty52  ttybc    ttye9  ttyr5      ttyu1  ttywe  ttyzb
ptyc4    ptyp1  ptyre  ptyub  ptyx8  tty12  tty53  ttybd    ttyea  ttyr6      ttyu2  ttywf  ttyzc
ptyc5    ptyp2  ptyrf  ptyuc  ptyx9  tty13  tty54  ttybe    ttyeb  ttyr7      ttyu3  ttyx0  ttyzd
ptyc6    ptyp3  ptys0  ptyud  ptyxa  tty14  tty55  ttybf    ttyec  ttyr8      ttyu4  ttyx1  ttyze
ptyc7    ptyp4  ptys1  ptyue  ptyxb  tty15  tty56  ttyc0    ttyed  ttyr9      ttyu5  ttyx2  ttyzf
ptyc8    ptyp5  ptys2  ptyuf  ptyxc  tty16  tty57  ttyc1    ttyee  ttyra      ttyu6  ttyx3
ptyc9    ptyp6  ptys3  ptyv0  ptyxd  tty17  tty58  ttyc2    ttyef  ttyrb      ttyu7  ttyx4
ptyca    ptyp7  ptys4  ptyv1  ptyxe  tty18  tty59  ttyc3    ttyp0  ttyrc      ttyu8  ttyx5


What on earth is a Teensy? Why have you mentioned arduino IDE if you aren't planning to use it? Have you considered a spellcheck? If you are asking a question about serial interfaces why did you not check serial devices?

TL;DR. Running Ubuntu might put your Q in the "off-topic" category. So - this is a "shot in the dark", but, if Ubuntu provides the raspi-config app, did you enable the serial port on the RPi in raspi-config?

@Milliways a Teensy is basically the same as an Arduino. It can be programmed using the Arduino IDE. I read somewhere that you might need the Arduino IDE installed to identify it as a valid USB device.

@Seamus I installed raspi-config and disabled/enabled the serial interface and the serial login sadly neither changed the result. I also checked the boot/firmware/config.txt if enable_uart=1 is set.

Fiddling with enabling serial has nothing to do with connected USB devices. What does devices does /sys/tty show?

@Milliways Do you mean just /sys/tty or ls /sys/tty in the terminal? Both return: "No such file or directory".

Oops I meant ls /sys/class/tty but you could also use ls /dev/tty*

@Milliways I added the output of ls /sys/class/tty to the question

If I plug a Pico into my Pi I see ttyACM0 and can connect with /dev/ttyACM0. Your problem is some external issue not an issue with the Pi.

@Milliways okay I will see. Thanks for trying :)
